# XNA SourceRectangle Not Drawing Texture In the Position I Want It

Tags: c#, xna, transparency, texture2d, rectangles

I've come across a situation with XNA's `sourceRectangle` on how it displays portion of a texture on the screen.

Let's say I have 2 simple shape textures - a square and a circle. The circle is positioned inside the square. The circle's position is being driven with
Mathhelper.Lerp(inside the square, outside the square, float x). If the circle texture goes down, it reaches the bottom edge of the square and gradually disappears, as if it reached the bottom edge of the actual game screen. `sourceRectangle` works fine in this case.

The problem occurs when the circle goes up and reaches the top edge of the square. Let's say the circle texture is halfway across the square's top edge. In this case, I just want the bottom half of the circle to show. When I tell `sourceRectangle` to only draw the bottom half, `sourceRectangle` does draw the bottom half, **but** it redraws that part on the top half of the circle texture. As a result, I have the bottom half of the circle drawn above the square's top edge, which isn't the desired effect.

I've come to the conclusion sourcerectangle does take the area of the texture you want drawn, but draws(or position) your desired area at the at the top of the texture first. Is there a workaround for sourcerect(in this case) to draw starting from the bottom, or any other option?

I've tried the Texture2d.SetData route to make rows of pixels transparent. That works, but I had to set graphicsdevice[0] to null, and I don't know how to get that texture back(or make it show on screen again). I've tried repositioning the texture right below the square's top edge everytime Lerp pushes the texture across square's top edge, but the animation becomes "choppy-looking" then.

[Handdrawn Sourcerect Description Link](http://www.breadmachinehq.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/CIMG0019.jpg)

**Resolved**

I figured out a solution that works pretty good for my needs. In my original post I stated I tried the `Texture2d.SetData()/GetData()` to make the pixels outside of square's boundary transparent. It work until i got an error saying I have to set graphicsdevice to null before setting the texture's data. I revisited that in the meantime and its now working perfectly.

My solution/errors:

```
Texture2D tempTex;

public Texture2d FormatTexture( Texture2D circleTex, int numOfRows)
{
    tempTex = new Texture2d(GraphicsDevice, circleTexture.Width, circleTexture.Height)

    //Each index in pixels[] will hold Color(r,g,b) data
    Color[] pixels = new Color[circleTex.Width * circleTex.Height];

    //Get every pixel's color info from the circle texture and store it in pixels[]
    circleTex.GetData<Color>(pixels);

    //Only edit the desired number of rows in the texture, not the entire texture
    for(int i = 0; i < circleTex.Width * numOfRows; i++)
    {
      //make pixel transparent via multiplying it by 0
      pixels[i] = pixels[i] * 0; 
    }

    //Bypass that graphicsdevice[0] = null error by setting data on a texture not  
    //currently using spritebatch (tempTex instead of circleTex)
    tempTex.SetData<Color>(pixels);
    return tempTex;
}
```

What I was doing wrong before was trying to set `circleTexture`'s data. Apparently you can't do that while its still on a graphics device. Instead, I created a new texture that's not on a spritebatch "tempTex" which is basically `circleTexture` with transparent rows. I've  noticed similar `T2D.SetData` error posts here, but I never found an understandable solution until now.

Comment: Are you using SpriteBatch? It sounds like you're having a sorting issue.

Comment: I'm using spritebatch.Draw, but the effect only works when the circle hits the bottom edge of the square. As a quick test, I only had the circle texture (50x50) in the middle of the screen. everytime I asked sourcerect to draw the bottom half, it places the bottom half at (0,0, 50, 25) not (0, 25, 50, 25).

Comment: Please post pictures - they're much easier to understand when it comes to graphics related issues than words.

Comment: I'm at work right now, I try to recreate it in Gimp in a few minutes

Comment: picture link of description added.

Comment: Are you specifying a sprite origin other that (0, 0) needed by this overload? Using a non-null (non-full) source rectangle combined with a 0,0 for the sprite origin will produce the effect you describe.

Comment: Problem solved. Due to my low reputation, I have to wait 2 hours before answering my own question. Answer will be up around 4(central time).

Comment: Or you could just add it to your question until then.

Comment: Added solution to original question.